# Confusion of how to use self define compare functions in std::sort and std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am trying to figure out the reasons why you define custom compare function differently for `std::sort` and `std::priority_queue`.

for example, 
for `std::sort` I can do something like this:

```
bool compare(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)
{
    return a[0] < b[0];
}
class foo
{
public:
    vector<vector<int>> f(vector<vector<int>> list)
    {
        std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), compare);
        return list;
    }
};


int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> t = { {2,1},{1,0},{3,7} };
    foo n;

    auto ans = n.f(t);
    for (vector<int> x : ans)
    {
        printf("x[0]: %d , x[1]: %d \n", x[0], x[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

after running the code the result is:

x[0]: 1 , x[1]: 0

x[0]: 2 , x[1]: 1

x[0]: 3 , x[1]: 7

However, if i define another function in `foo` like this:

```
vector<vector<int>> f1(vector<vector<int>> list)
{
    std::priority_queue<vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, compare> pq;
}
```

The compiler will not allow me to do this. The simple way for me to get around this is to make a struct inside the class like this:

```
struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)
    {
        return a[0] < b[0];
    }
};
```

Here is what i have so far:
From the en.cppreference.com, `std::sort` pass in a comparison function object, but priority_queue is passing in a Compare type. I assume this might be why I can't use the same compare function for the priority queue.

Another thought is that because `std::sort` is a function and priority_queue is a container, so we need to make it different?

This is all I have for now.

My most concern for this is why they are behaving so differently?
What is the major reason for this to be different? why we need it to be different?

p.s. Anyone have any good book recommendation for explaining the STL deeply and more concentrating on explaining the code of STL and why they made it like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're specifying `compare` as the 3rd template argument for `std::priority_queue`, which is not the correct type name. You need to specify it as an function pointer type, (and pass the function pointer as the function argument). e.g.

```
std::priority_queue<vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, decltype(compare)*> pq(compare);
```

or

```
std::priority_queue<vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, bool (*)(const vector<int>&, const vector<int>&)> pq(compare);
```

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is a function template, so when you can pass `compare` as the *function argument* and the *template parameter* could be [deduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) automatically (as the function pointer type); [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is a class template, so you have to specify the *template argument* explicitly, you just need to specify the type correctly (as the function pointer type, just as the type of the *template parameter* type of `std::sort` which is deduced automatically).

**EDIT**

Since C++17 we have [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), and then you could use it as

```
vector<vector<int>> f1(vector<vector<int>> list)
{
    // deduced T=vector<int>, Container=vector<vector<int>>, Compare=bool (*)(const vector<int>&, const vector<int>&)
    std::priority_queue pq(compare, list);
    return ...
}
```

then we don't need to specify the template arguments.

Comment: do this mean, the parameter I am passing in both are the same, which is a function pointer type? But since std::sort is a function template, the `compare` function has been implicitly converted to a function pointer type. On the other hand, the priority_queue doesn't have this implicit convert ability for the 3rd parameter, it only allows us to pass in a function pointer type?

Comment: according to what you said, we can infer that "For function type templates it is safe to pass in functions, but for container type templates we cannot do this?"

Comment: @MalcolmLiu Yes they're same function pointer type; the point is for function template the template argument could be deduced automatically, so you don't need to write sth like `std::sort<...>(...)` (of cource you can); but for `std::priority_queue` you need to specify the template argument explicitly as `std::priority_queue<...>`. Note that `compare` is not a type name, so you need to specify the type correctly.

Comment: Furthermore, why this is designed this way? why don't we make it all straight that both templates need to pass in the same thing(function type pointer)? And why allowing functions to have this implicit conversion is safe,  but not allowing the containers to have this property?

Comment: @MalcolmLiu Passing `compare` as the function argument, and specifying `compare` as template argument, are different things. They're supposed to be used for different purposes and behave differently. Answer revised.

Comment: So, in conclusion, the reason for deduced automatically is that we don't need to write that much stuff? I am guessing there should be something more beyond that. If this is the only reason for deduced automatically, then why we cannot make it happen for containers?

Comment: I think I should wait for your reply, and then post new questions. LOL Thank you very much for this. This has been bugging me for a long time, now at least I know where to research more. I think I should finish reading the link you provided before asking more.

Comment: @MalcolmLiu We have class template argument deduction since C++17, even it doesn't match your code exactly. See my revised answer.